# Operator cannot be applied to operands of generic type

Tags: c#, generics

Im writing a hierarchal state machine in C# and im using a generic type S in which will be fed an enum with different states for the different state machines.  I get the following error.  Check the comment in the code.

```
public interface IStateMachine
{
    public void fireTrigger(GameWideTrigger trigger);
}

public class StateTransition<T, S>
{
    public S StartState { get; private set; }
    public T Trigger { get; private set; }
    public S EndState { get; private set; }
}

public class StateMachine<S> : IStateMachine
{
    private List<StateTransition<GameWideTrigger, S>> transitions;

    public void fireTrigger(GameWideTrigger trigger)
    {
        foreach (StateTransition<GameWideTrigger, S> transition in transitions)
        {
            if (transition.StartState == CurrentState)  // CS 0019 Operator 'operator' cannot be applied to operands of type 'S' and 'S'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is `CurrentState`? I see no definition of it.

Comment: its just  public S CurrentState { get; private set; }

Comment: Indeed. `==` can mean a couple of different things (reference equality, a user-provided operator) and the compiler needs to figure out *at compile-time* which of those it is. It can't do that if it doesn't know anything about the type: `S` might be a value type with no `==` operator, and then what should happen? If you constrain `S` to be a reference type (`where S : class`) then the `==` will be allowed, as a reference comparison. Alternatively you can do `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y)`, which will call the type's `Equals` implementation

Comment: S will be an enum

Comment: You can constrain it to be an enum with `where S : struct, Enum`, but that still doesn't enable the `==` operator, so you will have to use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y)`

Comment: (See [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2694))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you canton7 for the correct answer:

> `==` can mean a couple of different things (reference equality, a user-provided operator) and the compiler needs to figure out at compile-time which of those it is. It can't do that if it doesn't know anything about the type: S might be a value type with no `==` operator, and then what should happen? If you constrain S to be a reference type (`where S : class`) then the `==` will be allowed, as a reference comparison. Alternatively you can do `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y)`, which will call the type's `Equals` implementation